# Is there a way to import/choose an external audio track to play over a movie in Audience/Videos?

Tags: release-loki, videos, audience

I have a video file that by default uses an audio track which is not in my preferred language. I also have an audio file that is intended to go with the video file, and this audio file *is* in my preferred language. I see the gear icon in the bottom right corner, as shown below, but the "Audio" and "Subtitles" options are greyed out.

[image]

**Is there a way to import an external audio file, like how you can import an external subtitle file?**

I would love to use this default video player because I think it looks better than any of the alternatives I've seen so far, but this is keeping me from being able to.